# CWAC Camera - turn off preview to save battery?

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing an app that needs to take photos in a time lapse fashion. I'm using CWAC Camera for android. The overall period in which to take these may be long, so constantly showing the preview drains battery fast. I'm wondering how to pause the preview for the timeout period.

The CameraView appears to have a restartPrewiew() method, but there's no stopPreview() or anything else similar that I could find.

In the source [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView.java#L529) there is a stopPreview() method, but it's private.

Does anyone know how to stop and restart preview to save battery? Any help much appreciated!